# React Native - how to trim a string

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, npm, react-native

I want to delete the whitespaces from the beginning and the end of a string. For example, given a string "   Test   ", I would like to receive "Test". I have tried JavaScript's methods and also some npm libraries, but they don't seem to work with React Native? Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: `" Test ".trim()` ?

Comment: Are any errors being thrown? Where in the project are you calling this method?

Comment: Try String.prototype.trim.call(your_str).

Comment: I use it like this:
`<TextInput
    ref="email"
    placeholder="E-mail"
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={email => this.setEmail({email})} />
.
.
.
setEmail = (email) => {
    this.setState(email.trim(), function(){
        this.validate();
    });
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your `setEmail` call and the ES6 syntax that you are using. When you do:

`email => this.setEmail({email})`

The transpiler transforms it into the following:

`email => this.setEmail({email: email})`

Which of course is an object.

Then, inside the function, you are trying to apply the `trim` function to an object, which of course results in failure. Try this instead:

`email => this.setEmail(email)`

You can read more on the ES6 syntax for object literals [here](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/).

Comment: I have the username. How can I remove the spaces (more than 1space and the space in prefix and suffix in a text). Above will replace all the space. Here if the user has two names, for example, Jiffan Joe. Here I need two names with a single space in between. Not all spaces

Comment: That's a different topic. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 3):

In case the string you want to trim is a state and you want to trim the spaces, but not to render the whole page, then you can do it directly as following:

```
this.state.text = this.state.text.trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

trim only cleans spaces. If you want to clean it all, including tabs, nbsp and so on, you can use this:

```
"\u2007 TEST \t\n".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // "TEST"
```